# How to install usb wifi adapter?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

I'm new to linux environment and I'm using both latest Ubuntu and Lubuntu on my systems.
I learned pretty much cmd lines but not every function they have. For example I can modify grub files using nano modifier >sudo nano...
So here's the thing. I have this USB WiFi Adapter TPLink WN727N which has a RT5370 chipset. I'm trying to install it and have found some good help at the link below. But I cant figure out what it means exactly.
So if anyone can help translate it for amateur people like me! :)
I specifically want to use Ralink Driver method and don't understand the line 4 of it.
"4. now just make, make install, and register your module with modprobe"
So how should I perform modprobe and to which directory address?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Tenda_W311M

ifconfig from Lubuntu 14.04

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:d4:4c:e0:5a  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:25472 (25.4 KB)  TX bytes:25472 (25.4 KB)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `lsusb` instead; `ifconfig` can only list interfaces, which have a driver. `modprobe` inserts the module into the current kernel... these commands need to be executed from within that directory: [MediaTek RT5370](https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/rt5370) ... download & extract the archive, `cd` into the resulting directory ...then the instructions of the link provided should work.  `modinfo` shows the kernel modules.

just a few years later ...

Answer (score 0):

From what I see your USB Wifi adapter should be working right after you plug it in. You only need to install the driver provided in the link if you are using `Ubuntu 12.04` or older. So what Ubuntu version are you using? I guess because of beeing new to the linux environment your are at least running `Ubuntu 13.04` or newer. Does your Ubuntu Distro recognize the Wifi adapter? Is it listet in the menu on the statusbar? What output does `ifconfig` give?

Comment: On my laptop I have Ubuntu 14.04 and it has actually recognized my internal wifi card and working no problem. But I tested my USB wifi on this and still not working, disabled internal wifi card in bios and inserted usb one and not working.

Comment: Thats mysterious because since Ubuntu 12.10 the driver should be in the kernel source. Could you provide a screenshot from the wifi menu in the statusbar with your USB wifi connceted?

Comment: I actually want this for my desktop which runs Lubuntu 14.04 and that doesnt support this usb wifi.

Comment: for my laptop with UBUNTU

Comment: oh I cant paste the results of if config here!

Comment: says too much characters!

Comment: But this is for my desktop lubuntu

Comment: this screen shot is for my lubuntu

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpwvggyd79duuc9/photo.JPG?dl=0